# Java: error inserting data into MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

I am using eclipse to insert data into MySQL, and it is only inserting the last row of the data.

```
String countryCodeSql = "INSERT INTO session" + "(sessionTimestamp,countryCode,countryName,visitorID)" + "VALUES ('"+timeStamp+"','"+countryCode+"','" + countryName+"','" + visitorID+"')";
myStat.executeUpdate(countryCodeSql);
```

these are my lines of codes, but I think it should be working fine as the codes below worked and the data were inserted.

```
String timeStampSql = "INSERT INTO conversation" + "(timestamp)" + "VALUES ('" +timeStamp+"')";
myStat.executeUpdate(timeStampSql);
```

Comment: Please show the full code here.  From what you showed us, only one insert _should_ be happening.  And _please_ consider using prepared statements.

Comment: You're trying to insert a single row, and a single row is successfully being inserted?  So... what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please use `PreparedStatement` ... they are SQLInjection safe and provide `set####` for every DB Type supported. And your query are missing some spaces, it could be a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the preparedStatement to insert data in the database when the data are dynamic. here is an example:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);

String query = "INSERT INTO session (sessionTimestamp,countryCode,countryName,visitorID) values(?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStmt.setString (1, timeStamp);
            preparedStmt.setString (2, countryCode);
            preparedStmt.setString (3, countryName);
            preparedStmt.setString (4, visitorID);

preparedStmt.execute();
```